# Calling non-Action methods from view-MVC .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to call a non-action method in a view. Can I do that? In other words, there is a method in my controller which returns a string. I want to call that method in my view (.cshtml) and show it in the view. All I could see was, the methods should return an ActionResult. But in my case I do not need a view returned just a string.

Comment: Do you mean an Ajax call, or a call on page load?

Answer (score 6):

The best way (and MVC convention way) to do this is to use a `ViewModel`.  Quick example:

**Model**

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult MyView() 
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            StringValue = CallMyMethod()
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyViewModel @*(use fully qualified namespace)*@

@Model.StringValue @*<-- this will print it out on the view*@
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is the correct solution. The model should talk to the view.

Comment: I used the above method. I am trying to use it in _layout.cshtml, so that when the the user logs in this method returns the string and display it on the page and all subsequent pages. However, getting the error - **bold**Object reference not set to instance of an object.**bold**

Answer (score 3):

You can do that if you want.

Although i wouldn't call it good practice.

You can call whatever methods you want on the view but you should try to keep you views as clean as possible and do the barest minimum of logic you require.

In your controller you could have this method below.

```
public string GetName(string name)
{
   return string.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>", name);
}
```

And in your view you could use it as below.

```
@{var c = new Controller();}

@c.GetName("My Name") //some other place in your view
```

Comment: you need a semicolon at the end of Controller().

Comment: @AmmarAhmed Thanks ... i missed that i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

You can return View/Partial view to other views by calling [Html.Action() or Html.RenderAction()](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx)

I've personally never had the need to return a value from a method that wasn't a base class of `ActionResult`, [as there are quite a few](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use case for a custom Helper.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Answer (score 0):

You can return a Json object from the controller with something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourFunction()
{
    return Json(new { stringContent = "Your String content here!" });
}
```

And then you can do an ajax call from your .cshtml like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/YourController/YourFunction',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
                $("#SomeElement").html(data.stringContent);
             },
             error: function () {
                 alert("error");
             }
});
```

Calling methods from your View that are in your Controller is not recommended as you are breaking the MVC pattern!